# Get all emails from outlook inbox using Python and save them into a local folder

Tags: python, loops, email, outlook

I want to save all my email messages from the inbox folder of outlook using Python. I can save the First or the last messages but couldn't understand how to get all the messages of the folder. Hence, I was trying to use a loop to iterate the code for all mails. I have tried to use the following code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
import re
os.chdir("D:\\emails")

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
print(inbox)
messages = inbox.items
message = messages.GetLast()
name = str(message.subject)
name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', name)+'.msg'
for message in messages:
   message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name)
```

This is not giving me any errors, but saving only the last mail, instead of saving all emails. Could you please help me to rectify the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is below

```
message = messages.GetLast()
name = str(message.subject)
```

and

```
message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name)
```

You calculate the name once (before the loop) and use it in the loop.

You need to calculate the name during the loop.

Comment: @shejomamu what is the comment above for?

Comment: @shejomamu - does it work as expected now? If it is - please up vote / accept the answer.

Comment: Yes @balderman, I have up voted your answer. Sorry for the previous typing mistakes. Your suggestion has made my code work just fine. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

The full code would look something like this.... (I got this answer from balderman)

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
import re
os.chdir("D:\\email")

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.items
for message in messages:
    message = messages.GetNext()
    name = str(message.subject)
    name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', name)+'.msg'    
    message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name)
```